# Unknown npm install syntax with gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have been following a gulp 'recipe' for [cleaning directories](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md). They suggest to use the vanilla node del module and to run `npm i gulp del`. What is that install syntax?

I've looked at the [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) docs and thought it might be a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope), however it doesn't follow the syntax exactly and the module doesn't seem to be installed in the appropriate locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is an alias for `install`.

Here you're installing both the `gulp` and `del` packages.